# Process to download Pi4j snapshot from Nexus repository?

Tags: java, netbeans, nexus, pi4j

Sorry I am new to this specific scenario. I would like to use these newest Pi4j libraries found at this link:
https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public/com/pi4j/pi4j-core/2.0-SNAPSHOT/
but its a ton of separate files unlike when I download the 1.2 version of Pi4j from https://pi4j.com/1.2/download.html

I've tried to download a few individual files to see if they contained the class definitions I expected but they didn't. Perhaps the naming conventions are throwing me off.
Should I download each file individually or is there some process I am completely unfamiliar with?
Sorry if this question seems silly but I'm at a loss.

Answer (score 0):

As V2 of Pi4J is work-in-progress and no "final" versions got released yet, you'll need to add extra repository info to your pom.xml file:

```
   <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>oss-snapshots-repo</id>
            <name>Sonatype OSS Maven Repository</name>
            <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
```

More info is available on https://v2.pi4j.com/getting-started/minimal-example-application